# sprintf %u gives wrong result

Tags: php, unsigned, printf, signed

Simple script, PHP 5.3.13, Windows 8, x32

```
<?php var_dump(sprintf('%u', -1380556906));
```

It gives me correct result

```
string(10) "2914410390"
```

the same thing with PHP 5.4.11, Freebsd 9.1, x64 gives

```
string(20) "18446744072328994710"
```

Why? How can I print signed int as unsigned int?

Comment: prints `string(20) "18446744072328994710"` on php v5.5.6 on Arch Linux x64 as well.

Comment: For reference: http://3v4l.org/oG7EU. I wonder why the behaviour changes 5.2.3 -> 5.2.4, maybe http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.4 will shed some light. Interesting; for me anyway. :)

Comment: That looks like an unsigned number, what's the problem? On a 64-bit architecture, unsigned ints are bigger.

Comment: I'm sorry in the first example architecture is x86. But how can print -1380556906 as 2914410390  in x64?

Comment: @Barmar the problem that signed -1380556906 = unsigned 2914410390, but not 18446744072328994710. And the seccond problem that 18446744072328994710 is bigger than PHP_INT_MAX

Comment: From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php - _The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers._

Comment: var_dump(sprintf('%u', -1380556908 & 0x00000000ffffffff)); This work's for me fine

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar has given the answer in the comments.

You are experiencing an unsigned integer overflow.

However as the integer size may vary in between architectures it is [either 32 or 64 bits long](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: I understand this, I thought that the first architecture was x64. And I just wanted to know how can i get 2914410390 from -1380556906 in x64, but i already found the answer